# I get errors whenever I try installing the TensorFlow python package

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip

System: Macbook Pro with M1 Chip, macOS Big Sur (version 11.4)
Python version: 3.82
Pip version: 21.2.4

I tried following the directions on this website: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Yet, no matter what I try, I always get this error message:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

I have tried looking for help from other stack overflow answers and none of them seem to help.

Comment: From the link you can see that the official tensorflow is only available for x86_64 on Mac, you need to install the apple tensorflow version.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you very much, I just solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your python version and it's compatible version for installing Tensor flow. Eventually when I wasn't able to install Tensorflow, I downgraded my python version and then successfully installed Tensorflow package.